# TinyMCE - Add button that changes direction of selected text

Tags: tinymce, multi-language, plugin-tinymce

Ok, I am going to create website in Urdu(rtl) & English(ltr) language that contain paragraphs like this:

```
<p style="direction:rtl">کیا حال ہے buddy? سب خیریت ہے؟</p>
```

You can see that sentence in not showing correctly. I want to change the direction of English words in sentense. like this:

```
<p style="direction:rtl">کیا حال ہے <bdo dir="ltr">buddy?</bdo> سب خیریت ہے؟</p>
```

You can see more clear differance at [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/feaek7fk/). How it is possible? Any idea?

Comment: I may be able to assist. Is you final goal, in the above example, to wrap the word 'buddy?' into the <bdo dir="ltr"> tag?

Comment: @ChristineCooper Thanks for help offer. Yes my goal is exactly that but only with push-of-button. More better if there is some short key.

Comment: @ChristineCooper any idea?

Comment: Yes my apologies, I have been ill for the past days and only recovering today. I will look through my code and post an answer for you within a day or two. I can confirm that I can definitely help you because we worked on a similar thing recently.

Comment: @ChristineCooper Thanks. What languages you are using in you website?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you, it adds the buttons and from the screenshot it looks like it is possible to achieve what you want: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rtl/